# How should i use collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, entity-framework, icollection

I have a list of strings which is populated by a query from database (entity frameworks):

```
 var accountIds = new List<string>();
```

Now I want to add two list of strings to my collection, for example, I have these two queries:

```
 using (var myketDB = new MyketReadOnlyDb())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                {
                    accountIds = myketDB.AppDevelopers
                        .Where(n => n.RealName.Contains(name))
                        .Select(e => e.Email).ToList();                  
                }                
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
                {
                    accountIds = myketDB.Accounts
                      .Where(e => e.Mail.Contains(email))
                      .Select(e => e.Email).ToList();
                }                 
            }
```

So with this query `accountIds` changes which I don't want this to happen. I want to have both lists in accountIds. something like this :

```
accountIds.add(//first query);
accountIds.add(//2nd query);
```

something like a union (I don't want to use union). I'm new to the collection list. many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add multiple items to existing list then `.AddRange` method will do this for you

```
accountIds.AddRange(myketDB.AppDevelopers
                        .Where(n => n.RealName.Contains(name))
                        .Select(e => e.Email).ToList());

accountIds.AddRange(myketDB.Accounts
                      .Where(e => e.Mail.Contains(email))
                      .Select(e => e.Email).ToList());
```

**Or** more simply, first collect query result to variable and then add these result to existing list like,

```
var appDevEmails = myketDB.AppDevelopers
                            .Where(n => n.RealName.Contains(name))
                            .Select(e => e.Email).ToList();

var accountsEmails = myketDB.Accounts
                          .Where(e => e.Mail.Contains(email))
                          .Select(e => e.Email).ToList();

accountIds.AddRange(appDevEmails);

accountIds.AddRange(accountsEmails);
```

**Further Reading:**

[List.AddRange(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: glad to hear. please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)